# Is there a way to keep already executed commands on some sort of cache in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Is there another program or app than would let you keep a list of previously executed commands on a cache or something similar, so you can then press a key and acces or search on a list of previously executed commands ? Going back with the up arrow looking for that scp or ffmpg  sucks a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Going back with the up arrow looking for a previous command sucks

`bash` has a built in buffer already called [command line history](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html).

You can use the following commands to manipulate the history:

- `!command` to execute the previous instance of `command`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> `command` will search for the previous instance of `command` and allows editing.

There are many more history commands available. See the Further Reading links below.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [history](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html) - Command Line history.
- [15 Linux Bash History Expansion Examples You Should Know](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/)
- [How To Search Shell Command History](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-history-search-command/)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Answer clarified.

Comment: man bash says that CTRL-S should search too (forward search I'm guessing), but it's never worked right with Mint or Ubuntu

Comment: @Xen2050 Doesn't work here either with Cygwin `bash`. No idea why. I don't have a Linux system to test on. Something to do with the terminal type maybe?

Comment: I think there's just *too many* options with bash, for every imaginable terminal that's ever existed  ;-)   There are a bunch of "meta" key combinations that I don't have set up either.

Comment: This answer is correct. To make it easier to search for a command in your history I do `history | grep "command I wanna look for"`

Comment: @Rhyuk That's covered in the further reading links ;)

Answer (score 0):

## grep

I just `grep` the history log file(s) directly, and feed it relevant keywords to search for..

---

**.bash_history**

```
$ grep 'scp'   ~/.bash_history
$ grep 'ffmpg' ~/.bash_history
```

**$HISTFILE**

```
$ grep 'scp'   "$HISTFILE"  
$ grep 'ffmpg' "$HISTFILE"
```